# JS: Is using a dictionary faster than looping through an array?

Tags: javascript, performance, loops, dictionary

I'm building some program in Nodejs, which will need to keep track **in memory** of  a large number of users. Also, i will have a function that filters a user by id. The code would look something like this:

```
const users = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'John',
        friends: [3, 6, 8]
    },
    {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Mark',
        friends: [567, 23]
    }
]

function getUserById(userId) {
    const user = users.filter(user => user.id === userId);
    return user[0];
}
```

The question is, whether this version is generally faster(each key is user id):

```
const users = {
    1: {
        id: 1,
        name: 'John',
        friends: [3, 6, 8]
    },
    2: {
        id: 2,
        name: 'Mark',
        friends: [567, 23]
    }
}

function getUserById(userId) {
   return users[userId];
}
```

My intuition says that the dictionary is faster. What are the facts?

Comment: Lets assume 100K users

Comment: your 100k users would appreciate when you use a database. If you really need to store them in memory you maybe want to take a look at redis

Comment: This state will be used to keep a track of users connected via SocketIO, this is why memory is used.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Key lookup time in objects is not guaranteed. It might also be O(n), but most engines will optimize it towards O(1) if you dynamically look up a key multiple times. Filtering an array is O(n), `.find()` however is twice faster on average:

```
  return users.find(user => user.id === userId);
```

Now the only datastructure that *guarantees* O(log n) lookup are `Map`s:

```
 const userMap = new Map(users.map(u => [u.id, u]));
 console.log(userMap.get("test"));
```

If you however plan to do that in a very large scale (100k is large), I would rather move that task to a database, as it is heavily optimized for those tasks. MongoDB would be easy to adopt, Redis would be very fast, there are many others out there.

Comment: Regarding the database: This will not just be a list of users of a site, but a list of users connected via SocketIO. This is why ill need to have an in-memory track

Comment: @sheff2k1 then I would store an additional property into the socket object directly.

Comment: Yes, i plan to put a "userData" property on each socket, but i would still need to keep track of all connected sockets, in order to sometimes perform some socket-specific task..

Comment: @sheff2k1 moving the users to a database also allows you to run multiple Nodejs Websockets in parallel, which will outrun a single thread in memory nodejs server.

Comment: Yes that's a good point. Note that i already have the users in an SQL database. This state object is just a way to create some correlation between the socket, and the logged-in user(The login system is totally separated from SocketIO ).

Answer (score 2):

I've written a small script that can be copy pasted to the console and shows the actuall data for this question and varifies in practice the answer of Jonas Wilms.

```js
function random_int_from_range(x, y) {
  return (x + Math.floor(Math.random() * (y - x + 1)));
}

function generate_name(length_min, length_max) {
  var letters = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
  var name_array = [];

  for (var i = 0; i <= random_int_from_range(length_min, length_max); i ++) {
      name_array.push(letters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * letters.length +1)));
  }

  return name_array.join('')
}

function generate_friends_array(length_min, length_max, num_users) {
  friends_array = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < random_int_from_range(length_min, length_max); i++) {
    friends_array.push(random_int_from_range(0, num_users - 1))
  }

  return friends_array
}

function generate_users_dict(num_users) {
  var users = {};
  for (var i = 0; i < num_users; i++) {
    users[i] = {
        'id': i,
        'name': generate_name(4,6),
        'friends': generate_friends_array(0, 20, num_users)
    }
  }

  return users
}

function generate_users_list_from_dict(users_dict) {
  var users_list = [];

  for (var key in  users_dict) {
    users_list.push(users_dict[key]);
  }

  return users_list;
}

function get_diff_in_seconds_from_two_milisecond_values(early_value, late_value) {
  return (late_value - early_value) / 1000
}

function get_user_by_id_from_dict(users_dict, user_id) {
  return users_dict[user_id]
}

function get_user_by_id_from_list(users_list, user_id) {
  const users = users_list.filter(user => user.id === user_id);
  return users[0]
}

function get_time_for_retrieval_of_item_from_object(object, object_length) {
  var function_names = ['get_user_by_id_from_dict', 'get_user_by_id_from_list'];
  var random_id = random_int_from_range(0, object_length - 1);
  var function_name = '';

  if (Array.isArray(object)) {
    function_name = function_names[1];
  }
  else {
    function_name = function_names[0];
  }

  var time_before_retrieval = new Date().getTime();
  window[function_name](object, random_id);
  var time_after_retrieval = new Date().getTime();

  return get_diff_in_seconds_from_two_milisecond_values(time_before_retrieval, 
  time_after_retrieval);
}

function test_retrieval_times(number_of_users, tests_num, object_type) {
  var users_dict = generate_users_dict(number_of_users);
  var users_list = generate_users_list_from_dict(users_dict);
  var times_array = [];
  var object = '';

  if (object_type == 'dict') {
    object = users_dict;
  }
  else {
    object = users_list;
  }

  for (var i = 0; i < tests_num; i++) {
    times_array.push(get_time_for_retrieval_of_item_from_object(object, 
    number_of_users));
  }

  return times_array;
}

function get_average_retrieval_time(object_type, number_of_users, 
                                    numbers_of_retrievals) {
  var retrieval_times = test_retrieval_times(number_of_users, numbers_of_retrievals, 
                                              object_type);
  var sum = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < retrieval_times.length; i++) {
    sum += retrieval_times[i];
  }

  console.log('average retrieval time for ' +  object_type + ': ' + sum / 
              numbers_of_retrievals);
}

var number_of_users = parseInt(prompt("Please enter object size", "1000000"));
var number_of_retrievals = parseInt(prompt("Please enter number of retrievals", 
                                    "100"));

get_average_retrieval_time('dict', number_of_users, number_of_retrievals);
get_average_retrieval_time('list', number_of_users, number_of_retrievals);
```

The results of the tests are printed to the console.

Answer (score -1):

Using a list of 10,000 objects.

I found that the dictionary look up was exponentially quicker than the array .find method.

https://jsbench.me/u1ll3uib1t/1

Interestingly `Map` & `Set` are the fastest with `plain obj {}` in second place and `arrays` way way behind.